# Redirect landing page component 5 seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to `Redirect` or `Switch` the following Hero React component after a 5 second delay using `React-Router`.

`<Redirect to="/home" />` redirect's the component to http://url.com/home instantly.

Any suggestions on how to handle this? Thx.

```
class Intro extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex w-100 h-100 mx-auto p-4 flex-column">
        <Header />
        <div 
          style={{
            paddingTop: '40px'
          }}>
        </div>
        <Hero />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Intro;
```

I've also tried using `setTimeout` as well

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: I'm using React Router v4

Comment: @nbokmans, my question is, "How do I `Redirect` or `Switch` the following `Hero` React component after a 5 second delay using `React-Router v4`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `history` prop injected by `react-router` and invoke the `push` method inside a `setTimeout`. You should do it in `componentDidMount`:

```
constructor(props) {
  // ...
  this.redirectTimeout = null;
}

componentDidMount() {
  const { history } = this.props;
  this.redirectTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    history.push('/home')
  }, 5000);
}
```

**Edit:** Make sure to clear the timeout to avoid redirects when you move out of the page before the 5 seconds are over, else you will still get redirected:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.redirectTimeout);
}
```

Comment: Hm.. Can you provide more detail as to where that would go? Your edit really added complexity and confusion for sure.

Comment: It's very straight forward, add the `componentWillUnmount` life-cycle method with `clearTimeout`. This will stop the timeout callback if a different route was triggered and made the component un-mount, This way it won't route to `/home` if user changed the route.

Comment: `componentWillUnmount()` should appear directly after `componentDidMount()`. Correct?

Comment: The order doesn't really matter imo but some linters warn about it

Comment: Thanks again @sagiv

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom DelayRedirect component.

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/JT501/4b0f60fb57b1410604b754fd9031150a

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect, RedirectProps } from 'react-router';

interface DelayProps {
  delay: number;
}

const DelayRedirect = ({ delay, ...rest }: RedirectProps & DelayProps) => {
  const [timeToRedirect, setTimeToRedirect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeToRedirect(true);
    }, delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [delay]);

  return timeToRedirect ? <Redirect {...rest} /> : null;
};

export default DelayRedirect;
```

Usage:

```
<DelayRedirect to={'/'} delay={1000} />
```